# Cookie not sent in Chrome Cross Domain Post

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cross-domain, cors

I want to provide a cross domain service using POST. I can see preflight OPTIONS call successful, but when I post, the cookie is not sent in Chrome. The same javascript and server code work for Firefox and Safari. What could be the problem? Here are the details:

Request URL:http://j.test.com/Post
Request Method:OPTIONS 
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:j.test.com
Origin:http://www.amazon.com
Referer:http://www.amazon.com/Gone-Girl-A-Novel-ebook/dp/B006LSZECO/ref=pd_rhf_gw_s_ts_2
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.amazon.com
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 04 Sep 2012 16:44:48 GMT
Server:nginx

I use jQuery:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://j.test.com/Post",
     xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
     },
     data: {
            referringUrl: document.URL
           },
     success: function(data) {
     },
     error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     }
  });
```

Comment: Did you found the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You muust set the flag withCredentials to true (http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/)

Answer (score 0):

You may also need `crossDomain: true` in your `jQuery.ajax()` call.